# Looking for an alternative to the Speedlifter Twist / quickly rotate handlebars solution

Tags: handlebars, parking

I'm looking for an alternative to the Speedlifter Twist: http://www.speedlifter.com/twist.php?L=en

The only function I'm interested in is the parking feature where I can turn my handlebar 90˚. I have a small apartment and it would really save a lot of space. I know of the flipphandle (http://www.bikesnapp.com/flipphandle.shtml), but it doesn't appear that the company ever actually put it into production. Has anyone seen anything affordable with similar functionality?

Comment: The website seems down for fliphandle.  Their facebook is here: https://www.facebook.com/flipphandle

Comment: Posted a question about purchasing on the flipphandle facebook page, but haven't gotten a response yet. I'm really interested in a solution to this, so I'll continue to keep this up to date with what I find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the n'lock: [Nlock](http://www.nlock.ch/). Which appears to be in production and come in a variety of sizes to fit different bars.  I have no actual experience with them but it looks like it meets the requirements you set out.

Comment: Thanks! This is the closest I've come to finding an alternative, though I still can't believe there's no company in North America making a similar product.

Comment: From the looks, Nlock has a very easy to pick lock mechanism, and the cable is also very easy to cut. The advantage is more about the twist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have quick release wheels you could remove your front wheel in order to turn the handlebars 90 degrees.  You could also get something like this[quick release mount](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002K2F876) to make your fork a little more stable.  Hang the wheel on the wall, or put it anywhere you have room.  I'd rather not have a quick release mechanism on my headset.